# Using ThreadPool threads in library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working on a .net core library that will get used mostly in web apps. This library is being built with performance in mind as this is the main design decision. There is some code that is fairly heavy and due to this, will get cached so that subsequent calls are quick. As you can imagine, the first call is slower and I don't want that. I want to execute this code at the earliest possible time to warm up the cache without affecting the other operations. I was thinking of using `Task.Start()` without `await`ing to to achieve this.

My question is, is it frowned upon to use threadpool threads in a library, i.e what is the etiquette on this? As this will be mostly used on web apps, I feel I don't want to interfere with the client's threadpool. That being said, the library will only use one background thread and this will be less than a second. Or should I just let the client take the performance hit for first calls?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly; it's perfectly legitimate to use multi-threading in a library; as a matter of fact: it happens all the time.

Basically, a lot of `async Task` methods do this in one way or another. ([Sometimes there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html))

If it's so heavy you need multiple parallel threads for a long period in time, than it's best to create an explicit initialize routine, and warn the caller in the docs.

[Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2) is typically used for such processing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code isn't async in nature, it is CPU bound, so I will have to use a background thread. I'm leaning towards giving the client the option to warm up or not on app start.

Comment: You're welcome: be advised: `Task.Run` is just 1 of the way's to span a background thread. Keep in mind: you probably want just 1, to solve this, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.7.2